# How to concisely express function iteration?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, iteration

Is there a concise, idiomatic way how to express [function iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function)? That is, given a number `n` and a function `f :: a -> a`, I'd like to express `\x -> f(...(f(x))...)` where `f` is applied `n`-times.

**Of course, I could make my own, recursive function for that, but I'd be interested if there is a way to express it shortly using existing tools or libraries.**

So far, I have these ideas:

- `\n f x -> foldr (const f) x [1..n]`
- `\n -> appEndo . mconcat . replicate n . Endo`

but they all use intermediate lists, and aren't very concise.

The shortest one I found so far uses semigroups:

- `\n f -> appEndo . times1p (n - 1) . Endo`,

but it works only for positive numbers (not for 0).

Primarily I'm focused on solutions in Haskell, but I'd be also interested in Scala solutions or even other functional languages.

Comment: Something using `iterate`, perhaps?

Comment: @pigworker iterate looks good. `\n f x -> iterate f x !! n` should work.

Comment: `until ((<= 0) . snd) (\(y,k) -> (f y, k-1)) (x,n)`. At the moment, `until` is still recursive, so it won't be inlined, and you'd get no unboxing and inlining of `f`, but in HEAD, it has been worker-wrapper transformed, and when that change is released, the compiler would write the loop for you.

Comment: Please turn your comments into answers so that we can up-vote them.

Comment: Fun thought (that you probably already know): this is exactly how [Church numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals) work. A number `n` is encoded as a function that composes its argument with itself `n` times.

Comment: @pigworker I like your answer the best so far, could you convert it to a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I like pigworker's/tauli's ideas the best, but since they only gave it as a comments, I'm making a CW answer out of it.*

```hs
\n f x -> iterate f x !! n
```

or

```hs
\n f -> (!! n) . iterate f
```

perhaps even:

```hs
\n -> ((!! n) .) . iterate
```

Answer (score 23):

Because Haskell is influenced by mathematics so much, [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definition) from the Wikipedia page you've linked to almost directly translates to the language.

Just check this out:

[image]

[image]

Now in Haskell:

```
iterateF 0 _ = id
iterateF n f = f . iterateF (n - 1) f
```

Pretty neat, huh?

So what is this? It's a typical recursion pattern. And how do Haskellers usually treat that? We treat that with folds! So after refactoring we end up with the following translation:

```
iterateF :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
iterateF n f = foldr (.) id (replicate n f)
```

or point-free, if you prefer:

```
iterateF :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
iterateF n = foldr (.) id . replicate n
```

As you see, there is no notion of the subject function's arguments both in the Wikipedia definition and in the solutions presented here. It is a function on another function, i.e. the subject function is being treated as a value. This is a higher level approach to a problem than implementation involving arguments of the subject function.

Now, concerning your worries about the intermediate lists. From the source code perspective this solution turns out to be very similar to a Scala solution posted by @jmcejuela, but there's a key difference that GHC optimizer throws away the intermediate list entirely, turning the function into a simple recursive loop over the subject function. I don't think it could be optimized any better.

To comfortably inspect the intermediate compiler results for yourself, I recommend to use [**ghc-core**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core).

Comment: is there anything to be gained by a binary strategy, similar to that used in exponentiation? take `f.f.f.f.f.f` as `g.g` where `g = f.f.f`?

Comment: reduce iterations. probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @benw: Sure, it would reduce the number of `(.)`s to evaluate, just like with the exponentiation. If you compile a highly contrived example without optimizations you might even be able to measure the performance difference!

Answer (score 15):

In Scala:

```
Function chain Seq.fill(n)(f)
```

See [scaladoc for Function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function$). Lazy version: `Function chain Stream.fill(n)(f)`

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not as concise as jmcejuela's answer (which I prefer), there is another way in scala to express such a function without the `Function` module. It also works when n = 0.

```
def iterate[T](f: T=>T, n: Int) = (x: T) => (1 to n).foldLeft(x)((res, n) => f(res))
```

To overcome the creation of a list, one can use explicit recursion, which in reverse requires more static typing.

```
def iterate[T](f: T=>T, n: Int): T=>T = (x: T) => (if(n == 0) x else iterate(f, n-1)(f(x)))
```

There is an equivalent solution using pattern matching like the solution in Haskell:

```
def iterate[T](f: T=>T, n: Int): T=>T = (x: T) => n match {
  case 0 => x
  case _ => iterate(f, n-1)(f(x))
}
```

Finally, I prefer the short way of writing it in Caml, where there is no need to define the types of the variables at all.

```
let iterate f n x = match n with 0->x | n->iterate f (n-1) x;;
let f5 = iterate f 5 in ...
```